# Laravel: use Vite::asset() in SCSS file?

Tags: css, laravel, sass, vite, laravel-10

I'm new to Laravel 10 and Vite.

In my Blade templates, I use:

```html
<img src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/img/image.jpg') }}" class="card-img" alt="">
```

I can't figure out how to use Vite::asset() in a SASS file, as for example:

```css
background-image: url('{{ Vite::asset("resources/img/image.jpg") }}');
```

Is this possible? How to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use any PHP code inside a SASS file, you just put the normalURL, that's it, it will autmatically see the file you want to include and Vite will include it (copy to the public folder).

So, your SASS should be like:

```css
background-image: url("resources/img/image.jpg");
```

Read the [`Introduction to Vite`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#introduction) again, so everything is clearer!

Comment: I just see I need to write `background-image: url("/resources/img/image.jpg");` with a heading slash

Comment: That is possible, I did not have the pleasure to use it, you could also use relative path (`../`) and it should work too